# What is the range of feedback resistors of LM2577 adjustable version?

Tags: boost, feedback

I am making custom boost converter with LM2577 adjustable version.

I have a question about selecting feedback resistors R1 and R2

For R1 and R2 formulas available in the datasheet, but they do not specify the range kilo or mega or just ohms.

Which range I should use?   Ohm range or kiloohm range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical application from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2577.pdf) shows feedback of a few k\$ \Omega\$.

[image: LM2577 typical application]

Digging a little deeper for an underlying reason, look at the input bias current on the feedback pin (which is attached to the error amplifier)

[image: LM2577 Feedback boas current]

At the maximum possible current, a resistance in the 100s of K\$ \Omega\$ or M\$ \Omega\$ would give a significant error from the feedback network; keeping the values below a few 10s of kohms minimises that error.

I would use resistors in the range of a few k\$ \Omega\$ for this.

Comment: 12.5k*800nA=1mV error .... Rule of thumb.  1mV or 0.1% error worst case per 10k equiv resistance value used